# Is it possible to zero the free space on a LUKS volume?

Tags: luks, sparse-files, loopback, fallocate-command

I want to have a LUKS volume as a loopback device pointing at a sparse file. Lets say I put a 20gb file on it, then later I delete it. How can I zero that area on the device itself so I can `fallocate -d` the loopback file to reclaim the space?

Answer (score 2):

Not answering the question as written, but to achieve the desired effect, you can open the luks partition like this.

```
$ losetup -f --show luksfile
/dev/loop0
$ cryptsetup open --allow-discards /dev/loop0 luksvolume
$ mount -o discard /dev/mapper/luksvolume /mnt/luksvolume
```

This makes the cryptsetup device obey TRIM commands, which makes the underlying file grow and shrink accordingly. The `mount -o discard` can be replaced with an occasional `trimfs`.

It should be noted, however, that using TRIM on luks partitions [could have security implications.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard.2FTRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_.28SSD.29)